# Identifying seasonality over 3 years for thousands of unique units with R

Tags: r, time-series, seasonality

I want to identify if there is seasonality of hundreds of thousands of items in a time series. I think a hypothesis test would be most appropriate instead of developing an actual forecast. I can't find a method that can run through thousands of items. I've played around with `ETS()` and `arima()` in R. `ETS` makes some nice visuals, but would be ridiculous to do for the entire population.

Example of one unit:

```
UNITCODE 98260311
QTY Startdate
655 Jan-16;
293 Feb-16;
885 Mar-16;
841 Apr-16;
155 May-16;
658 Jun-16;
871 Jul-16;
79  Aug-16;
787 Sep-16;
304 Oct-16;
520 Nov-16;
596 Dec-16;
```

Comment: Is the length of that example series typical?  That is, monthly observations for a year? Then you need methods apt for short time series. Specifically seasonal arima (SARIMA) will not work for such short series, you would need at least a couple of years.

Comment: It is 3 years of history on a monthly basis. The above was just an example of the data format.

Comment: Three years of monthly data would be an absolute minimum for SARIMA modelling, probably not enough.  Can you assume stationarity?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't not think I can assume the time series is stationary.

Comment: Can you test for cointegration then? I doubt three years of data will be enough ...

Answer (score 0):

There are two distinct approaches to modelling seasonality . One uses seasonal dummies in conjunction with level shifts and deterministic time trends . The second embodies seasonal ARIMA  . Both approaches also require down-weighting of anomolous data points detected via Intervention Detection schemes. Select a sample set of time series randomly and evaluate which of the schemes is most appropriate . Form a model comprehensive enough but not to comprehensive to determine a dominant approach . Estimate that modelling approach allowing for anomalies using step-down methods and review the results on a larger set of sample time time series ( randomly selected) to enable you to draw conclusions.